# Sort vector with fixed number of integers

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, integer

Vectorlist vl has a lenght of 100000000 with max. 101 different Integer values. What would be the best and fastest sorting algorithm?

I tried it with counting sort,(bucket sort), ..., but they are not fast enough. Every Integer (+ -) is valid. The 100000000 , 101 different Integers are random generated. Thanks for your reply! My best algorithm is about 0.620s.

Comment: I believe that insertion into a tree map will be fastest, where each value is the number of insertions of a given key. Essentially I'm suggesting an insertion sort on compressible data.

Comment: You can use `unordered_map` in c++ to hash the values and maintain count of each different value.

Comment: If you use a tree map then you get the sort for free.

Comment: @Bathsheba Agreed that `map` would get the sort for free but if number of different values are greater (say m) then we have to account for log(m) each time. So time would be n*log(m) . But in case of hash, it would be n + m*log(m)

Comment: The op should try and test both schemes.

Comment: @Bathsheba A tree-based approach is highly unlikely to be faster (in terms of physical time) than just e.g. directly quicksorting the array, due to cache locality reasons.

Comment: To solve it I think you should look into dynamic perfect hashing algorithms. Then you could go with standard counting sort.

Comment: I think that it would be better if we just didn't help this vampire.

Comment: Counting is obviously the fastest sort method for the specified conditions.  If you tried that correctly and it was "not fast enough" then nothing could be.  But what did you actually do, that you are calling a "counting sort"?  Maybe you did the wrong thing.

Comment: Thanks guys, this helped me a lot. It's not possible to use a tree map on insertion, cause i get the vector from another system. I will try your answers asap.

Answer (score 1):

Use an `unorder_set` to find unique the values, then put these unique values into a `vector` and sort them; and then put originals into an `unorder_multiset` to count the values, something like:

```
vector<int> v;
// fill v with values
unordered_set<int> s(begin(v), end(v));
vector<int> sorted_v(begin(s), end(s));
sort(begin(sorted_v), end(sorted_v));
unordered_multiset<int> v_count(begin(v), end(v));
for (size_t i = 0; i < sorted_v.size(); ++i)
    cout << "For the " << i << "th value == " << sorted_v[i] << " there are " << v_count.count(v[i]) << " of them." << endl;
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm) (see the comparison table of algorithms), we should use counting sort because we have not so much different values.
First, I supposed that our values are ints 0-100, and used the following code:

```
void sort(std::vector<int>& v)
{
    double start = std::clock();
    int* table = new int[MAX];
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX; ++i)
    {
        table[i] = 0;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        ++table[v[i]];
    }
    int cur = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < table[i]; ++j)
        {
            v[cur++] = i;
        }
    }
    delete[] table;
    std::cout << "count sort over char array took " << (std::clock() - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC << " s" << std::endl;
}
```

This code took `0.149s` on my computer versus `3.002s` used by `std::sort`.

This is a classic implementation of counting sort, but now try to speed up it, removing some excessive calculations:

```
void sort6(int* v, int size)
{
    double start = std::clock();
    int* table = new int[MAX];
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX; ++i)
    {
        table[i] = 0;
    }
    int* end = v + size;
    for (int* vi = v; vi < end; ++vi)
    {
        ++table[*vi];
    }
    int* cur = v;
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX; ++i)
    {
        int count = table[i];
        for (int j = 0; j < count; ++j)
        {
            *(cur++) = i;
        }
    }
    std::cout << "count sort with pointers over char array took " << (std::clock() - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC << " s" << std::endl;
    delete[] v;
    delete[] table;
}
```

This gives approximately `0.076s`.

Secondly, given that our values are not ints 0-100, I use the following algorithm:

- Find all 101 different numbers (considering uniform distribution).
- Sort these numbers.
- Lookup each of our 100000000 numbers in this array when performing counting sort.

Unfortunately, at the moment I have no time to implement this and check, but I'm sure the answer is out there.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the full implementation of the algorithm described by some other users above.
Total algorithm complexity is O(n).

```
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdint>

void special_sort(std::vector<int>& v, const size_t nExpectedMaxDifferentValues)
{
    typedef int_fast32_t Value;
    typedef size_t Count;
    static_assert(sizeof(Value) >= sizeof(int), "please define Value to int on this platform");

    struct ValHash
    {
        inline std::size_t operator()(const Value k) const
        {
            return k;
        }
    };

    std::unordered_map<Value, Count, ValHash> counts;

    counts.reserve(nExpectedMaxDifferentValues * 100);
    for (const auto x : v)
        ++counts[x];

    std::vector<Value> sorted_numbers;
    sorted_numbers.reserve(counts.size());
    for (const auto& p : counts)
        sorted_numbers.push_back(p.first);

    std::sort(std::begin(sorted_numbers), std::end(sorted_numbers));

    // fill vector with sorted data:
    int* p = v.data();
    for (const auto x : sorted_numbers)
    {
        for (Count i = counts[x]; i > 0; --i)
        {
            *p++ = x;
        }
    }
}
```

Main function to test speed:

```
#include <random>
#include <limits>
#include <time.h>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Initialize..." << std::endl;
    const size_t N = 100000000;
    const size_t M = 101;

    std::mt19937 gen(5); // use constant to easily reproduce the test
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> disInt(std::numeric_limits<int>::min(), std::numeric_limits<int>::max());
    std::vector<int> v1;
    v1.reserve(M);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < M; ++i)
        v1.push_back(disInt(gen));

    std::uniform_int_distribution<size_t> disIndex(0, M-1);
    std::vector<int> v2;
    v2.reserve(N);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        v2.push_back(v1[disIndex(gen)]);

    std::cout << "Sort..." << std::endl;
    const clock_t begin_time = clock();

    special_sort(v2, M);

    const double seconds = double(clock() - begin_time) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    std::cout << "Sorting took " << int(seconds * 1000) << " ms" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Program output from my notebook (compiled by MSVC 2013 Update 5 for **x86_64**, ran on Core i7-4700MQ CPU @ 2.40GHz):

```
Initialize...
Sort...
Sorting took 374 ms
```

There are a number of magic and half-magic optimizations to get this result:

- Use of own trivial hash function: -50%
- Use 100 as multiplier for hashtable bucket count: -50%
- Compile as x64 instead of 32bit code (x86): -25%
- Use C++11 foreach instead of equivalent with iterators: -33%

Comment: Why are you reserving 100 times more then you actually need in `counts.reserve(nExpectedMaxDifferentValues * 100);`?

Comment: Just reserving `nExpectedMaxDifferentValues` slows down the code with factor 2, but I wonder why...

Comment: I'm not sure 100% percent.
I have 100 multiplication exactly because it made the whole algorithm 2 times faster.
I had factor 2 previously, but algorithm was 2 times slower. I was sure factor 2 should be enough to stop thinking about hash collisions, but it is not true in this case.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Sergey's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34574991/1300910), you could run the count in parallel using multiple threads, which speeds up the process at least 2 times.

So instead of:

```
std::unordered_map<int, size_t> counts;
counts.reserve(nExpectedMaxDifferentValues * 100);
for (const auto x : v)
    ++counts[x];
```

we could spawn multiple threads that all do a part of the work (using Windows threading for demonstrational purposes only):

```
// Spawn 8 threads and spread the work
const int numberOfThreads = 8;
PartialResult partialResults[numberOfThreads];
HANDLE threadHandles[numberOfThreads];
const size_t partialSize = v.size() / numberOfThreads;
std::vector<int>::iterator it = v.begin();
for (auto i = 0; i < numberOfThreads; i++)
{
    partialResults[i].reserve = nExpectedMaxDifferentValues * 100;
    partialResults[i].begin = it;
    it += partialSize;
    partialResults[i].end = (i == numberOfThreads - 1) ? v.end() : it;
    threadHandles[i] = ::CreateThread(NULL, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)partial_count, (LPVOID)&partialResults[i], 0, NULL);
}

// Wait for all threads to finish
::WaitForMultipleObjects(numberOfThreads, threadHandles, TRUE, INFINITE);
for (auto i = 0; i < numberOfThreads; i++)
    ::CloseHandle(threadHandles[i]);

// Aggregate counts (this could also be done in parallel)
std::unordered_map<int, size_t> counts;
counts.reserve(nExpectedMaxDifferentValues * 100);
for (auto i = 0; i < numberOfThreads; i++)
    for (const auto x : partialResults[i].counts)
        counts[x.first] += x.second;
```

Where `PartialResult` and `partial_count` is:

```
struct PartialResult {
    std::unordered_map<int, size_t> counts;
    std::vector<int>::iterator begin;
    std::vector<int>::iterator end;
    size_t reserve;
};

DWORD WINAPI partial_count(_In_ LPVOID lpParameter)
{
    auto partialResult = (PartialResult*)lpParameter;
    partialResult->counts.reserve(partialResult->reserve);
    for (auto it = partialResult->begin; it < partialResult->end; it++)
        ++partialResult->counts[*it];
    return 0;
}
```

Above code leads to execution time of 390ms instead of 860ms on my setup and could be improved by also aggregating the partial counts in parallel.

Comment: I have found additional optimization, so parallel code will work in 160 ms on average.
I will also update your post to have cross platform code.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that for this task counting sort is the most suitable.
However, if all that you need is just to print sorted list of integers as quickly as possible, consider not saving integers at all - but only their counters in map.